# An unhandled exception when try to input data to MySQL Table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new in learning C# and MySql using Visual Basic Community 2015, I'm trying to make simple CRUD, but I'm confused when I Run the Program and try to input data to MySql Table because it always shows message

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Siswa,Total Biaya SPP,Sisa Bayar SPP,Keterangan) VALUES

is there any solution for this?

```
public partial class Crud : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password='';Database=db_csharp1");
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
        public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public Crud()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Crud_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetRecords();
    }

    private void btnTambah_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter ("INSERT INTO siswa (NIS,Nama Siswa,Total Biaya SPP,Sisa Bayar SPP,Keterangan) VALUES ('"+textNIS.Text+"','"+textNamaSiswa.Text+"','"+textBiayaSPP.Text+"','"+textSisaBayar.Text+"','"+textKeterangan+"')", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds,"siswa");
        MessageBox.Show("Added!");
        textNIS.Clear();
        textNamaSiswa.Clear();
        textBiayaSPP.Clear();
        textSisaBayar.Clear();
        textKeterangan.Clear();
        GetRecords();
    }
    private void GetRecords()
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from siswa", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "siswa");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "siswa";
    }
```

Comment: Please use paramaterized statements for your SQL statmements otherwise your code is prone to SQL Injection attacks. From the error that you posted, your Insert statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use Parametrized query to fill your `Dataset`. Now since the string used to initialize the `SqlDataAdapter` becomes the `CommandText` of the `SelectCommand` property of the `SqlDataAdapter`. So you can add your parameters like this:

```
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter ("INSERT INTO siswa (`NIS`,`Nama Siswa`,`Total Biaya SPP`,`Sisa Bayar SPP`,`Keterangan`) VALUES (@textNIS,@textNamaSiswa,@textBiayaSPP,@textSisaBayar,@textKeterangan)", conn);

adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textNIS","%" + textNIS.Text + "%");
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textNamaSiswa","%" + textNamaSiswa.Text + "%");
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBiayaSPP","%" + textBiayaSPP.Text + "%");
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textSisaBayar","%" + textSisaBayar.Text + "%");
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textKeterangan","%" + textKeterangan + "%");
```

Not sure if your field `textKeterangan` value should be `textKeterangan.Text` or `textKeterangan`. You can take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your column names. Use ` in your column names.

```
INSERT INTO siswa (`NIS`,`Nama Siswa`,`Total Biaya SPP`,`Sisa Bayar SPP`,`Keterangan`)
```